# Windows logon without start screen on a HYPER-V guest

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I am configuring Windows Enterprise as a HYPER-V guest on a Windows 10 host. The only guest user on the guest has no password. I have used netplwiz to disable the password requirement. I have also activated  "Don't display the Getting Started welcome screen at logon" with gpedit. Still when I use vmconnect to connect to the guest, a start screen appears for the user with his icon, user name and a button to press to log on. I want vmconnect to directly display the desktop without anything before that. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, vmconnect intentionally refuses to pass credentials to VMs on the local host, so if you are connecting from the there, you'll have to use something else like remote desktop if you want to skip the login screen. You'll need to enable it on the guest, and if you insist on connecting to an account with a blank password, you also need to allow blank passwords for remote desktop in gpedit.

Otherwise, you can use vmconnect from the command line or in a shortcut and pass the credentials as parameters:

`vmconnect ServerName VMName /user UserName /password Password`

There are other options, to see them all: `vmconnect /?`